# Searchkit: filter activity results in a query to show activity with earliest date

Tags: searchkit

I have a list of cases- created in searchkit. And I've added in activity cases with a status of "scheduled".

Mostly- but not always this returns one activity per case. But sometimes it shows more.

Is there a way of filtering these activity results to show the scheduled activity with the earliest date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this. Group by case id and transform on activity date with `min`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Demerit. Was trying to get my head round field transformations on dates, and ot quite getting it.